# SIGABRT: Precondition failure: imported node deleted before its value was read

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Since the `beta 5` of `Xcode 11` launched, I have had to update the code. You know the drill. However, there is this weird runtime error that is surviving the changes, and I cannot figure out why it happens.

I started trying to corner it within my original code, but surprisingly it also happens in the simplest test project that I managed to come up with: a TabView with a table.

The procedure to have the Xs simulator crash with SIGABRT while changing to another tab in runtime with the error:

> "xxxxxxx[23089:4642999] precondition failure: imported node deleted
>   before its value was read: 90"

If the user enters the detailview clicking in a row, it does not crash; just run the app and press the second tab.

I have revised the view building, the object ... nothing. It even crashes when changing the row view to a simple Text. I also removed @Binding , etc. to rule out Combine.

Please, let me know if any of you guys see something. It only crashes in Beta 5, not in Beta 2.

```
//  This file can be used in a new TabView app in Xcode 11 beta 5
//  ContentView.swift


import SwiftUI


class TestObject : Identifiable, Hashable{

    let identifier: String


    init() {
        self.identifier = UUID().description
    }

    static func == (lhs: TestObject, rhs: TestObject) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(identifier)
    }

}

struct RowView: View {
    let aTitle: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(aTitle)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let aObject: TestObject
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(aObject.identifier)
            Spacer()
        }
    }

}


struct ListNavegableNoBinding: View {
    var testObjects: [TestObject]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(testObjects, id: \.self) {
                someObject in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(aObject: someObject)) {
                    RowView(aTitle: someObject.identifier)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var tests : [TestObject] = [
        TestObject(),
        TestObject(),
        TestObject()
    ]


    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){

            VStack{
                Text("First View")
                    .font(.title)
                ListNavegableNoBinding(testObjects: tests)
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image("first")
                    Text("First")
                }
            }
            .tag(0)

            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)

                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("second")
                        Text("Second")
                    }
            }
            .tag(1)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same simulator crash in beta 5 both with my full project and a simple example like yours. For now, I've replaced by TabView with an HStack and replaced the tabs with a series of NavigationLinks. Not ideal of course, but it will keep me moving until the next beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xcode Beta 6 (just released yesterday), my TabViews are working properly again. No more SIGABRT errors. So, time to upgrade!

Comment: I can confirm. The sample code is free from SIGABRT with beta 6.

Comment: I still have the problem with Xcode version 11.0 (11A420a)

Comment: Me too, I can repeatedly trigger it, although intermittently, by moving between tabs whilst viewing detail views in a NavigationView and then selecting a new detail view from a List.

Comment: XCode 11.2 still like this

Answer (score 3):

I still have this issue on Xcode 11.0 (11A420a). The crash happens only when NavigationLink used inside a dynamic List. the only work around for me was to use a ForEach inside the List like below:

```html
List {
    ForEach(store.items, id: \.id){ item in
        NavigationLink(destination: YourDefinitionView()) {
            Text("some text")

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I used a ForEach inside and i still get the crash :(

Answer (score 2):

Xcode Beta 5 is really a step backward in terms of quality. My project is totally broken. First, the known issue with crashing Shape and also with the Tab and List views.

I have the following code which doesn't work anymore. It crashes on selecting the seconds tab:

```
struct WorkoutList: View {
    var workoutCollection: WorkoutCollection

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(workoutCollection.workouts) { workout in
                NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutDetail(workout: workout)) {
                    WorkoutRow(workout: workout)
                }.accessibility(identifier: "workout")
            }.accessibility(identifier: "workoutList").navigationBarTitle(Text("workouts.title"))
        }
    }
}
```

When replacing the dynamic List with a static one it works without any issues:

```
struct WorkoutList: View {
    var workoutCollection: WorkoutCollection

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List() {
                NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutDetail(workout: workoutCollection.workout[0])) {
                    WorkoutRow(workout: workoutCollection.workout[0])
                }.accessibility(identifier: "workout")
            }.accessibility(identifier: "workoutList").navigationBarTitle(Text("workouts.title"))
        }
    }
}
```

I think we have to wait for Beta 6.

Comment: As predicted, with XCode 11 Beta 6 everything works again!

Answer (score 1):

I still have this issue on Xcode 11 GM... 
I have three tabs all with lists inside, and whenever I change tabs while scrolling the current view the SIGBART crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a TabView with a list inside every tab, and my app is totally broken now. It seems like it has trouble dereferencing the List component. We'll have to wait, but I hope for a hotfix to release very soon.

Comment: I solved it, but then sometimes it still happened until the XCode 11.2.1 release where it was mostly fixed.

Comment: How did you fix it ? I am facing the same issue. In my app, I have 2 tab views. 2nd tab view has a navigation bar which consists of a segmented control.

Answer (score 0):

Similar situation here. Instead of using a List however, I am using Form and that seems to cause this error when ever I tap from that Tab to any other tab or vice versa. Weird, weird stuff.