# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT because of a button inside a NavigationView -> List -> Section

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, reswift

Since Xcode 12, I have a **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**, here is the detail of the error:

> 2020-10-20 00:01:20.989409+0200 App[23604:1417143] precondition failure: imported node deleted before its value was read: 90

The crash appears when I quickly change tabs.

I thought the crash was from ReSwift but after investigation, when I comment the button, the crash disappear (I tried to only comment the dispatch but the app still crash).
Here is the code:

```
struct Profile: View {
    @ObservedObject private var state = ObservableState(store: appStore)
    
    var genderOptions = ["‍♂️ Male", "‍♀️ Female", " Other"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Manage account")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ChangePassword()) {
                        Text("Change password")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.state.dispatch(signOut(state: self.state.current, store: appStore))
                    }) {
                        Text("Deconexion")
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: DeleteAccount()) {
                        Text("Delete account")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .font(.system(size: 17))
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text((self.state.current.firebaseAuthState.userDetail?.firstName)!))
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this button can provoke a crash like this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57303951/14351818)